# Can I send binary data directly over HTTP?

Tags: http

I mean, can I expect to work

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 27

[27 bytes of binary data]
```

And the binary data is arbitrary binary data, not Base64 encoded with *all* 8 bits in use, not 7 bits. The receiving application is custom application that would know what to do with the data.

Of course, I could test, but I need to know if this is likely to work with real server and over web, not just between both client and server running on a localhost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RFC 2046 defines the *octet-stream* subtype](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1) as follows:

> **4.5.1.  Octet-Stream Subtype**
>
> The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains
> arbitrary binary data.

And [RFC 2045 defines *binary data* in context of MIME messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-2.9) as follows:

> **2.9.  Binary Data**
>
> "Binary data" refers to data where any sequence of octets whatsoever
> is allowed.

Comment: That's not really the reason why HTTP  - indeed - can transport binary.

Comment: @JulianReschke So what’s the actual reason?

Comment: @JulianReschke That’s not really a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Gumbo: well, it's the explanation. (WRT answer: you *can* send application/octet-stream over Mail, but you need additional encodings for that; this proves why your line of argument is totally misleading: you're looking at the wrong layer)

Answer (score 12):

Yes. HTTP/1.1 message header blocks are text, but the payload of messages can be arbitrary binary data.